# SQL - Join with default if it's not possible to match

Tags: sql, db2

I have two tables which look like this:

Table 1:

```
+---------+---------+-------------+
| Activity| Area    | Responsible |
+---------+---------+-------------+
| Cooking | Meat    |   Peter     |
| Cooking | Vegan   |   Sia       |
| Cleaning| Kitchen |   Paul      |
| Cleaning| Toilets |   Selina    |
+---------+---------+-------------+
```

Table 2:

```
+---------+---------+-------------+
| Activity| Area    | Day         |
+---------+---------+-------------+
| Cooking | Meat    |   Monday    |
| Cooking | Vegan   |   Monday    |
| Cleaning| Garden  |   Friday    |
| Cleaning| Toilets |   Friday    |
+---------+---------+-------------+
```

Now I want an SQL to join them, so that I can see the responsible persons for each day.

I think the standard SQL would look something like this:

```
SELECT DAY, ACTIVITY, RESPONSIBLE 
FROM TABLE_2 2
LEFT JOIN TABLE_1 1 
ON 1.ACTIVITY = 2.ACTIVITY AND 1.AREA = 2.AREA
```

But now there are some rows which can not be joint (e.g. Cleaning Garden).
In that case (if it is not possible to join) I want always Peter to be responsible for it.

Can I do that in one join (maybe with a CASE statement?) or how would you do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use numbers for table names, even if DB2 allows it.  Numbers should be numbers.

You are looking for `COALESCE()`:

```
SELECT t2.DAY, t2.ACTIVITY, COALESCE(t1.RESPONSIBLE, 'Peter') as Responsible 
FROM TABLE_2 t2 LEFT JOIN
     TABLE_1 t1 
     ON t1.ACTIVITY = t2.ACTIVITY AND t1.AREA = t2.AREA;
```